# data("draggable") is undefined in jQuery-ui-1.10.3

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I have problem after upgrading jquery and jquery ui with new version. I am getting data("draggable") undefined inside droppable.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yx3gW/53/) shows my problem.

```
$(this).data("draggable").originalPosition = {
      top: 0,
      left: 0
}
```

It works with **jQuery 1.8.3** and **jQuery UI 1.9.2**.
But not working when I use **jQuery 2.0.2** and **jQuery UI 1.10.3**.

You can check using firebug at line number 39 which shows undefined when you are using latest jQuery files.

Please help me or give any alternatives.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it got renamed, try

```
$(this).data('ui-draggable')
```

Comment: Is there any other changes related to positions?
If you can give some link where all updates are listed, it helps me a lot. I have some other problems while revert so.