# Jquery snapElements undefined drag events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The problem:

I'm getting a javascript error from code that I got from a working jsfiddle and im not sure where the problem is coming from. I'm trying to understand how jquery drag events work. The test is triggering results from draggable items based on where the item is placed.

Here is the working js fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/uYpnW/5/

I'm going to be doing something a bit different but it will work for my purposes. I need to trigger events on snapped like assigning ids and names etc to the element that was dropped. I also need it to create another element from dropping in case the user needs multiple items however for now im just trying to understand where my error is coming from and what I am not understanding.

Stacktrace:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'snapElements' of undefined

$.draggable.stop @ jquery.gridder.html:37$.Widget._trigger @ jquery-ui.js:815$.widget._trigger @ jquery-ui.js:6513(anonymous function) @ jquery-ui.js:415$.widget._mouseStop @ jquery-ui.js:6126(anonymous function) @ jquery-ui.js:415$.widget._mouseUp @ jquery-ui.js:1018(anonymous function) @ jquery-ui.js:415$.widget._mouseUp @ jquery-ui.js:6148(anonymous function) @ jquery-ui.js:415$.widget._mouseDown._mouseUpDelegate @ jquery-ui.js:959jQuery.event.dispatch @ jquery-1.10.2.js:5095jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle @ jquery-1.10.2.js:4766
```

Code
    
    
    
      
        Subnet Test

```
  <style>
    #snaptarget { height: 300px; background-color: white; background-image: url('http://egords27.edumsko.ru/images/users-files/egords27/ood/132421643034.jpg');}
    .draggable {
        width: 90px;
        height: 80px;
        padding: 5px;
        float: left;
        margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
        font-size: .9em;
        background-image: url('http://7-themes.com/data_images/out/21/6839204-gradient-background.jpg');
    }

    .snap {
        width: 300px;
        height: 100px;
        margin-bottom: 25px;
    }
  </style>

  <script>
    $(function() {
        $(".draggable").draggable({
                snap: ".snap",
                stop: function(event, ui) {
                    /* Get the possible snap targets: */
                    var snapped = $(this).data('draggable').snapElements;

                    /* Pull out only the snap targets that are "snapping": */
                    var snappedTo = $.map(snapped, function(element) {
                        return element.snapping ? element.item : null;
                    });

                    /* Display the results: */
                    var result= '';
                    $.each(snappedTo, function(idx, item) {
                        result += $(item).text() + ", ";
                    });

                    $("#results").html("Snapped to: " + (result === '' ? "Nothing!" : result));
                }
            });
      $( "#draggable" ).draggable({ snap: true });
    });
      function buildSubnet(id){
          var html_string = $('div.snapContainer').html()
          $('div.snapContainer').html(html_string + "<div id='"+ id +"'>" +
                  "<div id='snap-one' class='snap ui-widget-header'>Snap 1</div>"+
                  "<div id='snap-two' class='snap ui-widget-header'>Snap 2</div></div>"
          );
      }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" onClick="buildSubnet(this.id);">Add Subnet</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>


<div class="container-fluid" style="top:500px;">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-9" >
            <h1 class="page-header"></h1>

            <div class="snapContainer">

            </div>

            <br style="clear:both">
            <div id="draggable" class="draggable ui-widget-content">
                <p>Oh Snap!</p>
            </div>
            <div id="draggable" class="draggable ui-widget-content">
                <center>ASG</center>
                <div class="asgGroup">

                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="results"></div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [data("draggable") is undefined in jQuery-ui-1.10.3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18850289/datadraggable-is-undefined-in-jquery-ui-1-10-3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.data('draggable')` was renamed to `.data('ui-draggable')` in newer versions of jquery-ui